# Error while trying out touch actions using Appium

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-android

Below is my code:

```
package AppiumPackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileBrowserType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

public class AppiumClass {
    AppiumDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;
    String AppURL = "https://www.ndtv.com/";

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() throws MalformedURLException {

        // Create an object for Desired Capabilities
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

        capabilities.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", "C:/Users/Madankumar/Desktop/Chrome Driver/chromedriver.exe");

        // Name of mobile web browser to automate. ‘Safari’ for iOS and ‘Chrome’
        // or ‘Browser’ for Android
        //capabilities.setCapability("browsername", "Chrome");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME,MobileBrowserType.CHROME);

        // The kind of mobile device or emulator to use - iPad Simulator, iPhone
        // Retina 4-inch, Android Emulator, Galaxy S4 etc
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "919d8316");

        // Which mobile OS platform to use - iOS, Android, or FirefoxOS
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

        // Java package of the Android app you want to run- Ex:
        // com.example.android.myApp
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");

        // Activity name for the Android activity you want to launch from your
        // package
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");
        capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", false);

        // Initialize the driver object with the URL to Appium Server and
        // passing the capabilities
        driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSearchAppium() throws Throwable {

        driver.get(AppURL);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='notnow']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        TouchActions actions=new TouchActions(driver);
        actions.longPress(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='scroll__nav-link active-nav']"))).perform();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        actions.flick(20, 0);


    }    

    /*
    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
    */

}
```

On running the class from Eclipse IDE getting below error:

> May 12, 2018 12:12:25 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS`enter code here`
>   FAILED: testSearchAppium
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen
>       at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions.(TouchActions.java:38)
>       at AppiumPackage.AppiumClass.testSearchAppium(AppiumClass.java:77)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
>       at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)

[image: Jar Dependency as below screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

`TouchAction` class related to **Appium JAVA Client** jar,not related to selenium.

Remove `import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions` package and import **Appium JAVA Client** jar.

Do your code like this :

```
public void testSearchAppium() throws Throwable 
{ 
   driver.get(AppURL); 
   Thread.sleep(2000); 
   MobileElement notNow=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='notnow']"));  
   TouchAction actions=new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) driver); 
   actions.tap(notNow).perform(); 
}
```

Comment: Added this import
import io.appium.java_client.PerformsTouchActions;
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
Modified the code as 
public void testSearchAppium() throws Throwable {  
  driver.get(AppURL);
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  WebElement notNow=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='notnow']"));
  //notNow.click();
  TouchAction actions=new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) driver);
  actions.tap(notNow);

Error as "FAILED: testSearchAppium
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver cannot be cast to io.appium.java_client.PerformsTouchActions"

Comment: Getting the same error, but im using Eventfiringwebdriver so my code is like below 
 new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) (AppiumDriver)driver), but still getting unable to cast the eventfiringwebdriver to appiumdriver... any idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

The working solution for this issue is in the following link.

[ClassCastException with new Appium-java TouchActions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458726/classcastexception-with-new-appium-java-touchactions?answertab=active#tab-top)

Re-writing the solution here again

Use `io.appium.java_client.TouchAction` class.

### Step 1

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
```

Here driver is an instance of AppiumDriver.

### Step 2

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("locator"));

action.tap(new TapOptions().withElement(new ElementOption().withElement(ele))).perform();
```

With the new implementation of TouchAction you cannot directly pass weblement.

### dependency used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope it helps.